# VSCode Snippets not working inside Vue's template/script/style tags

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm new to vscode and can't get snippets to work properly inside of Vue files. They work in **`/snippets/vue.json`**:

```
{
  "<template></template>": {
    "prefix": "template",
    "body": [
      "<template>$1</template>"
    ]
  }
}
```

This works, as long as it is written in the `vue base layer` but not inside `script/template/style` tags. I've tried adding it to `vue-injection-markdown.json` which I thought is used for exactly that but it doesn't work. I've also created a `vue-html.json` file and added the json there but it also doesn't make the snippets work:

```
{
  "hello": {
    "prefix": "hello",
    "body": [
      "blub"
    ]
  } 
}
```

I've installed both these plugins:

- Vue Language Features (Volar)
- TypeScript Vue Plugin (Volar)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try turning on `Editor: Quick Suggestions` `on` for `strings`.

Comment: @Mark I did but it did not help.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that:

- javascript.json snippets work inside the `<script>` part of a vue file
- html.json snippets work inside the `<template>` part of a vue file
- vue.json snippets only work in an empty vue file (or at least, outside the template and script tags)
- global.json snippets, of course, work everywhere

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted. It seems lrgely "Thanks".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited to be more complete and remove the "thanks". I think it's valuable because nobody has mentioned javascript.json yet and it took me a little while to figure that out. I would have just commented on the answer above but I'm not allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it has to be defined either in `global.code-snippets` with a `html` scope or in the `html.json` file.